# I want to paste an embed video but it's always at the bottom, how can I solve that?

Tags: html, css, video

I'm working a lil project for my band. I added a responsive invisible navigation bar at the top of my index page, but what I want to add now are two things. An embed video and a little image above it.

So I'll upload an image for you guys to see my intentions: [image]

The problem is that when I paste the embed code video from YouTube, it goes to the left-bottom of the page. I tried to center the video and I could do it, but still in the bottom. I'll paste my html and css. Thank you:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  background-position: center center;
  background: url(img/1.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

section {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

header {
  padding: 0 100px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  transition: .5s;
}

ul {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  float: right;
  transition: .5s;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

ul li a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 20px 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #262626;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: .5s;
}

ul li a:hover {
  color: #985f82;
}

iframe {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.toggle {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 26px;
  color: #262626;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
}

@media (max-width:992px) {
  .toggle {
    display: block;
  }
  header {
    padding: 0 0;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  }
  header ul {
    width: 100%;
    top: -4px;
    display: none;
  }
  header ul.active {
    display: block;
  }
  header ul li a {
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffff;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>massaviu</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Spectral:400i&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.0.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.toggle').click(function() {
        $('ul').toggleClass('active');
      })
    })
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <section>
    <header>
      <a href="#" class="logo"><img src="img/logo.png"></a>
      <a class="toggle">MENÚ</a>
      <ul class="active">
        <li><a href="#">concerts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">discografia</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">galeria</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">contacte</a></li>
      </ul>
    </header>
  </section>
  <div class="videowrapper">
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Gv75MHGDsKA?controls=0" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to set `margin-bottom` or `padding-bottom` for your video?

Comment: I've already solved it. It was not included in the "section". Thank you, though.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I've got that stupid problem that my videowrapper was not into my section...

Comment: With the "responsive css" answer it is not required to insert the `<div class="videowrapper ">` into the section.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for responsive centered Youtube iframes

Edit: updated the css, BS4 method using `::before`

```
.videowrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 60%; /* example desktop width */
  margin: 0 auto; /* center */
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.videowrapper::before {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  padding-top: 56.25%; /* or 75% on 4:3 youtube */
}
.videowrapper iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 0;
}
@media (max-width: 992px) {
  .videowrapper {
    width: 90%; /* example phone width */
  }
}

<div class="videowrapper ">
  <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Gv75MHGDsKA?controls=0" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```